# Extract Multiple Strings from Paragraph

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

How do I extract more than one email from a paragraph and output the result to a console?

```
var pattern:RegExp = (/^\b[-._0-9a-zA-Z]+@[-._0-9a-zA-Z]+[\.]{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]+[\.]?[0-9a-zA-Z]\b$/i);
var asd:String;
asd=tt.text;
trace(asd.match(pattern));
```

Comment: What problems are you having?  As long as your regex is good for email, it should return every match in an array.

Comment: it return "null" when I have 2 separate emails in the string.

Comment: To clarify "tt" is a TextArea.

Comment: That's because your regex is faulty. Try removing the `^` and `$` from the string.

Comment: it almost there except only the first email could trace, the others are ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex pattern instead: `([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `g` to the end of your `RegExp` pattern to make it a *global* search, and hence return all the matches, which will be returned in an `Array`.  Eg.,

```
var pattern:RegExp = (/foo/g);
```

BTW, Grant Skinner has a great Flex/AIR app to develop and test regex patterns: [Online Version](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/)